# Sitecore Azure Index AddIncludedTemplate not adding base templates items to index

Tags: azure-search

I have an azure index 
and I would like to add to index all items that based on some parent template

```
 <include hint="list:AddIncludedTemplate">
                  <ISearch>{30AFB887-AE6E-450A-BE4F-C59D26A875F7}</ISearch>
                </include>
```

but during rebuild no items go to index,
If add specific template that based on parent (ISearch) to list, it processing successufly and I can see it at index.

How to activate validation by root template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can, unless something was changed recently that I missed.

Normally you would need to extend the basic crawler to be able to do this. So the idea being, you would create something like:

```
<include hint="list:AddBaseTemplate">
    <BaseTemplate>{30AFB887-AE6E-450A-BE4F-C59D26A875F7}</BaseTemplate>
</include>
```

And then extend the appropriate document crawler to include the logic.

A summary of how that could work can be found here: [Custom indexes in a Sitecore Helix architecture](https://ggullentops.blogspot.ch/2016/02/custom-indexes-in-sitecore-habitat.html)

While the post addresses the problem from a Helix angle, the base problem is the same as yours.

Comment: Wrote an update to the article for Solr recently: https://ggullentops.blogspot.be/2018/01/custom-sitecore-documentoptions-solr.html  No version for Azure yet, but as the Solr version is very similar to the Lucene one, I would assume an Azure Search version should be similar as well.